# How determine maven version for org.netbeans.swing.outline?

Tags: java, swing, maven, netbeans, mercurial

[Here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/) is a link to mercurial source code with netbeans. And there is [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.netbeans.api/org-netbeans-swing-outline) in maven repository. How determine what commit in sources corresponds to what version in maven repo?

**Note**

I understand that jars in maven repo appears much later then commits in mercurial, but some of jars can be "mapped" somehow?

**Btw**

Netbeans team uses ant for build, but somebody publish builded sources into maven repository may there are som sources with maven pom files?

Comment: Does your question mean which version to use for a specific commit made to the source code?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources contains the following file with java manifest:

```
o.n.swing.outline/manifest.mf
```

So the algorithm is:

1. donwload jar from [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.netbeans.api/org-netbeans-swing-outline) with some version.
2. open manifest file and see `OpenIDE-Module-Specification-Version`
   value.
3. Download other jar if value is different from source `manifest.mf`

Also do not forget to add `http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/` as repository. Do not know why `mvnrepository` can display artefact, can transfer jar to you, but can not send jar via maven.